# Реализовать обход foreach для своей коллекции

Tags: java

В учебных целях нужно было самостоятельно реализовать связные списки и сделать так, чтобы был возможен обход через foreach. Как я понял, нужно в коллекции реализовать Iterable и создать класс реализующий Iterator. Вопрос в том, что именно делать в методе интерфейса Iterable

```
 public void forEach(Consumer action)
```

и методе интерфейса Iterator

```
 public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super E> action) throws NullPointerException
```

Comment: В `Iterable` вам нужно, разумеется, реализовать метод `iterator()`, который возвращает — что? — итератор.

Comment: Это да, но яведь про forEach(Consumer action) писал

Comment: можно ничего не делать, [`Iterable.forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) и [`Iterator.forEachRemaining`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#forEachRemaining-java.util.function.Consumer-) - `default`-методы, т.е. у них есть реализация в интерфейсе (в справке описано ожидаемое поведение).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раз специалисты по Java не отвечают, и [@Barmaley пока не вернулся](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4280/10105), попробую написать я.

```
public class MyLinkedList<T> implements Iterable<T> {

    // имплементация вашего класса

    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new MyLinkedListIterator();
    }

    private class MyLinkedListIterator implements Iterator<T> {

        private MyListNode curr;

        public MyLinkedListIterator() {
            this.curr = MyLinkedList.this.head; // голова списка
        }

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return this.curr != null;
        }

        public T next() {
            if (!this.hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            T value = curr.value; // значение в текущем узле
            curr = curr.next;     // следующий узел
            return value;
        }

        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }
}
```

Больше ничего делать не надо, это компилируется. Теперь можно писать:

```
MyLinkedList<Integer> l = new MyLinkedList<>();
for (Integer v : l) {
    System.out.println(v);
}
```

Comment: Появляется ошибка приведения типа, требует Object 

    for(Object o:list)
        {
            System.out.println(o);
        }

Comment: @mcstarioni: У меня компилируется: http://ideone.com/E6OTTG

Comment: Нашел ошибку, при объявлении класса итеатора я ставил еще один <T> .